How to parse Ansible URI module get request result?
I am trying to hit the rest API on a Gerrit server to access the list of ssh keys via ansible. Here is the code:
- name: Get all the SSH public key from gerrit server
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: 'https://git.test.com/r/a/accounts/self/sshkeys'
    user: <username>
    password: <password>
    method: GET
    return_content: true
  register: data

- name: print returned json data
  debug:
    var: data.content

But the data.content format is completely weird and I can't seem to be able to filter it at all.
Here is the data.content:
{

"data.content": ")]}'\n'[{\"seq\":1, \"ssh_public_key\":\"<public-key>\", \"comment\":\"<comment>\"},
{\"seq\":2, \"ssh_public_key\":\"<public-key>\", \"comment\":\"<comment>\"}

}

I am trying to use data.content[0].comment but it returns UNDEFINED VARIABLE.
How do I filter this dataset in ansible?

That looks like a bug in Gerrit. I see the same thing using e.g. https://gerrithub.io:
$ curl -n  https://gerrithub.io/a/accounts/self/sshkeys
)]}'
[{"seq":4,"ssh_public_key":"ssh-rsa ...","encoded_key":"...","algorithm":"ssh-rsa","comment":"me@red.example.com","valid":true},{"seq":5,"ssh_public_key":"ssh-rsa ...","encoded_key":"...","algorithm":"ssh-rsa","comment":"me@blue.example.com","valid":true}]

That's not "completely weird"; that's a valid JSON object preceded by some random text (which appears to be the terminal bit of another quoted JSON object). Fortunately, it looks like the bug is consistent, which makes it easy to deal with; we just ask for the second line of text:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Get all the SSH public key from gerrit server
    ansible.builtin.uri:
      url: 'https://gerrithub.io/a/accounts/self/sshkeys'
      user: "{{ gerrit_username }}"
      password: "{{ gerrit_password }}"
      method: GET
      return_content: true
    register: data_raw

  - set_fact:
      data: "{{ data_raw.content.splitlines()|last }}"

  - name: print returned json data
    debug:
      var: data

That prints the expected, nicely formatted JSON result:
TASK [print returned json data] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "data": [
        {
            "algorithm": "ssh-rsa",
            "comment": "me@blue.example.com",
            "encoded_key": "...",
            "seq": 4,
            "ssh_public_key": "ssh-rsa ...",
            "valid": true
        },
        {
            "algorithm": "ssh-rsa",
            "comment": "me@red.example.com",
            "encoded_key": "...",
            "seq": 5,
            "ssh_public_key": "ssh-rsa ...",
            "valid": true
        }
    ]
}

And we can process the values in the response without having to do anything unusual:
  - debug:
      msg: "algorithm: {{ item.algorithm }}"
    loop: "{{ data }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.seq }}"

Which produces:
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=4) => {
    "msg": "algorithm: ssh-rsa"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=5) => {
    "msg": "algorithm: ssh-rsa"
}


If there no possibility that a response would contain more lines, it would make sense to replace .splitlines()[1] with .splitlines() | last - this will allow to continue using the playbook without changes once that bug gets fixed.

Good call! I'll update the answer.
